# Install Boot Camp 6 Without Internet Connection

Tags: bootcamp, macos

I'm using an early 2015 MacBook Pro and just updated it to El Capitan. Right now I want to install Windows 10 on my MBPr using Boot Camp. But the problem is, if I don't connect to the internet, Boot Camp Assistant will fail to install saying that it can't download additional software. I already downloaded the Boot Camp Support Software before so I don't want to waste a time to redownload it again.

Is there any solution for Boot Camp 6 to keep installing Windows without internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually do it without using [Boot Camp Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468). [This is the best guide I have found](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/) ([archive 2016-07-09](https://web.archive.org/web/20180709033156/http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/)). You will have to create the partition then manually install the drivers once Windows is installed.